# Can initialization of a template class member be delegated to client?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have faced with the following problem: how to initialize static Proxy which holds object that is provided as template parameter.

Here is my code snippet which shows the situation:

```
template<class SharedState>
  class TToolbar : public ImplCustomToolBar
  {
  public:
    virtual const ICustomToolbarsSharedState* const GetSharedState() const { return &sharedState_.Get();}

  private:
    // intent: static constructor for static SharedState initialization
    class SharedStateHolder
    {
    public:
      SharedStateHolder()
      {
        ToolbarsSharedState_.Initialize();
      }
      const SharedState& Get() const { return ToolbarsSharedState_;}
    private:
      SharedState ToolbarsSharedState_;
    };
    static SharedStateHolder sharedState_;
  };

// I need TToolbar::SharedStateHolder sharedState_;
```

As it is unknown what template parameter will be provided, I can't use explicit specialization of template for the static member initialization.

So the only solution I found: clients of TToolbar should do initialization themselfs. But I think that it is error prone solution.

Question: what weaknesses are in my solution and what is the proper way of dealing with such situation?

Comment: That's a dependency injection problem, see how `std::vector::emplace` solves it, or the [general pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @didierc Oh, thank you very much, I have never heard about this pattern. I know all patterns from Gof4 and thought it is enough. Could you please give me some reference on other patterns? If you post your answer I might accept it (of course after I do get acquainted with  injection pattern)

Comment: @didierc I read about dependency injection, I recall that I have faced with it before. How this pattern can be applied to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to delegate the construction of `TToolBar` to a factory, which knows about that shared state (basically, that's what `SharedStateHolder` does), and pass it to a protected constructor of `TToolBar`, which only that factory may use, by being `friend` with `TToolBar`. Objects needing such toolbar would have to go through the factory to get one.

```
template<typename SharedState>
class TToolBar {
    friend class TToolBarFactory;
    // ...
    protected:
        TToolBar(SharedState *shared){
            // ...
        }
        // all other constructor also protected
};

class TToolBarFactory{
public:
       TToolBarFactory();
       TToolBar<SharedStateImpl> *makeToolBar();
        // other toolbar pseudo constructors
};
```

Now `SharedState` construction is delegated to a dedicated class, which should be a singleton to ensure that toolbars all carry the same state.

Alternatively, since the `SharedState` instance is static, you can simply make a static method to set that variable once for all, and have the factory call it when it is instantiated. Then you would not need to pass it to `TToolBar` constructor (like I did above), and allow other objects to create them directly.

We may consider `TToolBarFactory` as a constructor for the `TToolBar` *class*, rather than its instances.

Note that this problem is orthogonal to the fact that `TToolBar` is parameterized on `SharedState`: you could make the factory directly provide specialized instances of `TToolBar` (like I did), or generalize it to a template, with a constructor a la `std::vector::emplace`, which is templated on the contained data constructor parameters.

```
template <typename SharedState>
class TToolBarFactory {
public:
    template <class... args>
    TToolBarFactory(Args...args){
        TToolBar<SharedState>::setSharedState(new SharedState(args...));
        // remaining factory init code.
    }

    // this could also be a variadic templated function
    TToolBar<SharedState> *makeToolBar(){
        return new TToolBar<SharedState>();
    }
};

// example 

class SharedStateImpl {
public:
    SharedStateImpl(int i, float f){}
};

// the factory instance
TToolBarFactory<SharedStateImpl> factory(42,3.14);

int main(){
    TToolBar<SharedStateImpl> *toobar = factory.makeToolBar();
}
```

---

If I understood your problem, it is really about having `SharedState` constructed outside `TToolBar`, because.you don't want that class to make any assumpions about `SharedState` constructors. My solution is a bit heavy weight. You could definitely do the same by simply making `SharedStateHolder` a template parameter of `TToolBar`, and keep all the initialization details there.

Comment: thank you, I got the idea about dependency injection using constructor, I think your solution introduce some excessive complexity. My aim is to reduce complexity. Thank you for a good explanation! +1 for the answer, but I can`t accept it as it addresses my question only partly(check the header of the question)

Comment: Yes, I realized I got a bit carried away, especially after seeing the other answer. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: that is my fault, I omitted the word static in the header of the question, I meant "Can initialization of a template class static member be delegated to client". So your answer solved the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static local variable of a member function:

```
template<class SharedState>
class TToolbar : public ImplCustomToolBar
{
    virtual const ICustomToolbarsSharedState* const GetSharedState() const
    {
        static SharedStateHolder sharedState_;
        return &sharedState_.Get();
    }
};
```

The compiler is responsible for ensuring that the static is unique.

Or, if one wants to get rid of that Holder class:

```
template<class SharedState>
class TToolbar : public ImplCustomToolBar
{
    virtual const ICustomToolbarsSharedState* const GetSharedState() const
    {
        static SharedState sharedState_;
        static bool initialized = false;
        if (!initialized)
        {
            sharedState_.Initialize();
            initalized = true;
        }
        return &sharedState_;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you. I have considered such solutions. I like the first one, I think that it addresses the part of my question "proper way of dealing with such situation", but remaining one is still uncovered(and this is the most important for me). +1 But I can't accept your answer.